# Calculated Constants in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

In Swift >= 2.1, is a calculated constant within a function recalculated every time the function is called? For example, if I'm doing something like:

```
let nonDecimalSet = (NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet()).invertedSet
```

within a function, is nonDecimalSet re-calculated every time the function is called? I could define the constant in the class, but it's nice to have it in the function for readability.

Comment: @Cristik how does your edit add value?  The [tag:swift] and [tag:swift2] are not synonyms.

Comment: From the wiki of the tag: `Use this tag only for questions directly related to changes in version 2.x`. This post doesn't contain questions related to that. The edit message was due to an early enter key, and this is why didn't had the explanation

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's recreated every time.  You might like this solution:

```
func check() -> Bool {

    struct Static {
        static let nonDecimalSet = (NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet()).invertedSet
    }

    return Static.nonDecimalSet.longCharacterIsMember(UnicodeScalar("A").value)

}
```

In this case, `nonDecimalSet` is only created the first time `check` is called, in a thread-safe way (using `dispatch_once` under the hood).

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following:

```
func myFunc() -> NSCharacterSet {
    let nonDecimalSet = (NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet()).invertedSet
    return nonDecimalSet
}

print(myFunc()) // "<__NSCFCharacterSet: 0x7f8379c14cd0>\n"
print(myFunc()) // "<__NSCFCharacterSet: 0x7f8379d0bf10>\n"
```

Notice that the function returns two different objects when called multiple times.  After the scope of `myFunc` ends, any objects left in that scope are released.  Thus, calling the same function multiple times will cause `nonDecimalSet` to be reallocated every time.

If you're looking to reuse this component throughout the object's life, consider making `nonDecimalSet` a class variable, setting and initializing it in the class's `init` method

Comment: Uh, I guess I could have done this myself:  thanks for going through the trouble.  I'll probably create it as an instance or static var; i just don't like the verbiage...

Comment: @pickwick No worries.  Please feel free to follow up with additional questions if you have any.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways of doing it, but I ended up doing this in a separate file:

```
let _nonDecimalSet: NSCharacterSet = (NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet()).invertedSet

extension NSCharacterSet {

    static func nonDecimalSet() -> NSCharacterSet {
        return _nonDecimalSet
    }
}
```